# How to apply authorization to whole controller except one method

Tags: node.js, jwt

I have added an `AuthGuard` on the `UsersController` class but I want to exclude one method in this controller from authorization.

Is it possible to exclude a single method from authorization?

I have added my code below:

```js
@UseGuards(AuthGuard('jwt'))
@ApiUseTags('Users')
@Controller('users')
export class UsersController {
  constructor(public service: UsersService) {}
  get base(): CrudController<UsersService, UserEntity> {
    return this;
  }
  @Override()
  async createOne(@ParsedParams() params, @ParsedBody() body: UserEntity) {
    const username = body.username, email = body.email;
    const qb = await getRepository(UserEntity)
    .createQueryBuilder('users')
    .where('users.username = :username', { username })
    .orWhere('users.email = :email', { email });
    const _user = await qb.getOne();
    if (_user) {
      const error = { username: 'username already exists' };
      throw new HttpException({ message: 'Input data validation error', error }, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
    return this.base.createOneBase(params, body);
  }
  @Post(':id/avatar')
  @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file', {
    storage: multerDiskStorageConfig('users', 'avatar'),
  }))
  async uploadAvatarFile(@Param() params, @UploadedFile() file: any) {
    const userObject = await this.base.service.findOne();
    userObject.avatar = file.path.replace(PUBLIC_ROOT_PATH, '');
    return this.base.updateOneBase(params, userObject);
  }
}
```

Comment: what framework are you using?

Comment: @RidgeA I am using Express js framework.

Comment: This is not a pure ExpressJS. You are using decorators, DI and TypeScript.
Please refer to your framework documentation

Comment: @RidgeA Ok thanks. But do you know how to apply that jwt module to a controller according to the Express js pattern.